# RPM can't find shared library from another RPM

Tags: shared-libraries, rpm

I have two RPMS that I made (lib.rpm and program.rpm), one containing a shared library eg. libtest.so, libtest.so.1, libtest.so.1.0. The other containing a single binary that is linked to the shared library eg. test_program.

I installed lib.rpm on a new machine with no problems. Copied over test_program and ran it fine. I then build program.rpm containing test_program, again no problems. But when I do a rpm -ivh program.rpm I get:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libtest.so.1() (64bit) is needed by test_program-0.1-1.x86_64
```

Yet, when doing a ldd on test_program it clearly finds the file at /usr/lib64/libtest.so.1.

Both my spec files are the bare minimum. Besides the package description I only added an entry under %files and AutoReqProv set to no.

So what gives?

Comment: what does 'rpm -q --provides lib_rpm_name' give?

Comment: Just because `ldd` sees it, doesn't mean the RPM database knows about it. `rpm -qlp lib.rpm` will show you the files that the `lib` RPM is installing (that RPM is aware of). E.g., if you are doing something to generate or link `libtest.so.1` in `%post`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: 'rpm -q --provides lib.rpm' gives `test = 1.0.0-1`. rpm -qlp lib.rpm gives `/usr/lib64/libtest.so /usr/lib64/libtest.so.1 /usr/lib64/libtest.so.1.0`.

Comment: Can you try adding a 'Requires: lib.rpm' to your program.rpm spec to see what happens?

Comment: @Nghia Is the lib compiled 64 or 32 bit? You app seems to look for 64 bit but the rpm seems to provide 32 bit one

Comment: @Forrest, When I try to install the RPM it still says `libtest.so.1.(64bit) is needed by test_program-0.1-1.x86_64`. I assume it found libtest, because when I change the 'Require:' to a non-existent lib it complains about it not being found. @Dmitry Yudakov, they are both 64bit, I compiled on CentOS 6.3 64bit. I didn't type the corrected output of 'rpm -q --provides' is `libtest = 1.0-1 libtest(x86-64) = 1.0-1`

Comment: Could you please post your spec file for both RPMs?

Comment: @Forrest, here are the two spec files http://pastebin.com/jCVZA9Mb

Answer (score 1):

In the [pastebin_link](http://pastebin.com/jCVZA9Mb) you gave I noticed

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

I think that causes not filling `Provides` data of the rpm - because of this the info about the files doesn't go to rpm database.

The solution could be removing `AutoReqProv` or setting it to `yes`.

**Edit:** *According to Nghia's comments it doesn't help:*

<del>Not sure why you need this, but if you really do, mentioning explicitly</del>

```
Provides: /usr/lib64/libtest.so /usr/lib64/libtest.so.1 /usr/lib64/libtest.so.1.0
```

<del>will probably solve your problem.</del>

Comment: Setting to AutoReqProv: yes works! But setting it to "no" and using Provides, as you suggested, doesn't work. The manual says "provides" specifies a "capability". I'd be curious to know a working solution using "AutoReqProv: no".

Comment: Only turn off "`AutoReqProv`" if you really, *really* know what you are doing. Why do you think you need to unset it?

Comment: I was using a copy and paste spec file from a previous project. I wasn't aware AutoReqProv: yes was the norm. Now I know.